# Dynamic conditions related to radio buttons in excel

Tags: vba, excel

How to make the conditions of radio button dynamic? for eg. if i have one radio button "yes" in A100 and the condition related to it is appearing in A103. And,  if i am inserting the row i want both(button and its value) to get shifted accordingly .

```
Sub OptionButton21_Click()
  Range("A103") = " Not Applicable "
End Sub
Sub DynamicRange()
  'Best used when only your target data is on the worksheet

  'Refresh UsedRange (get rid of "Ghost" cells)
   Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

  'Select UsedRange
  Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a named range**

1 -Select the target cell (i.e. `A103`) and give it a name in the "Name Box" on the top-left of the screen. Suppose you chose the name "MyTargetName"

2- Make the control to move with cells.

```
Right-click the control --> Format control --> Properties --> Move but dont size with cells
```

3- In VBA code, refer to the target cell by its name instead of its address:

```
Sub OptionButton21_Click()
  Range("MyTargetName") = " Not Applicable "
End Sub
```

This will make the referenced target shift correctly, along with the control, whenever new rows are inserted.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful